# extent reports with selenium and java - how to see progress of tests on screen/console

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, testng

I am using selenium + java + testng + extent reports combination. 
A)I would like to see the progress of tests on the console so that its easy to monitor the progress. However extent reports can seen only in the end and does not show anything on screen while test is in progress.
B) How to combine testng and extent reports output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Q:** I would like to see the progress of tests on the console so that its easy to monitor the progress.

**A:** Just add @AfterMethod or @BeforeMethod which will print current state of your suite using TestNG data (e.g. ITestResult, ITestContext).

**Q:** However extent reports can seen only in the end and does not show anything on screen while test is in progress.

**A:** Nope, you are wrong. It provides real-time reporting. See [basic-usage](http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/java/#basic-usage).

**Q:** How to combine testng and extent reports output.

**A:** What do you mean? You may log all output with extent methods. See [examples](http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/java/#examples).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to get the text of the ExtentTest.info(LogStatus.INFO, "..............") which go into the extent report file to also come to the console in which the tests are executing in real time. I tried using the ExtentReports.flush function but it does not print it on to the console.

Comment: Have you configured any logger? You can make a wrapper for ER logging methods to make them send output to report and console.

Comment: that is what I finally did, but thank you for updating here.